# Looking for a short story about the icy end of the world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

More than a decade ago, I read a short story about a small group of people at the end of the world. The story was premised on some sort of mass-produced device which took ambient heat and turned it into power. The devices had been overused, and now the world was freezing.

I think the people were essentially bandits; the main character may have been a woman who lured men to her house and killed them for their body heat? There was also a strong implication that one person she had done this to was an alien who had come to warn that the devices were destroying the world.

I think the story was in a hardbound collection, and I think the collection was from the late 70's or very early 80's.

(Calling it a "short story" is just meant to distinguish it from a full novel — it may have actually been a novella or similar.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the Frederik Pohl story "[The Snowmen](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57235)".  It actually is a very short story.

One of the characters repeats a remark from the alien: "He said it was extremely high technology that produced a device that took heat out of its surrounding ambient environment, but had we ever thought of what would happen when *all* the heat was gone?"

You can read it in the December 1959 issue of **Galaxy Magazine** (where it first appeared) at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1959-12).

[image]

Comment: That's exactly right! I can even picture the book, knowing now that it's Pohl. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. You described it very well, I recognized it immediately.

Comment: What did they do with the power to keep it from turning back into heat?

Comment: They ignored the laws of thermodynamics.  Or at least Pohl did.